# We're sorry, but something went wrong on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm facing a problem with my rails app on the production environment, the situation is that I have a embed code for displaying the video which is further having two links for the quality selection of video, i.e 360p and 720p. The default quality is 720p. A user can select a quality depending on the bandwidth. Now the problem is that the 720p works file but 360p show the error message, "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Below is the log file generated when I look for heroku log in the terminal:

```
http://codeshare.io/4hi1K
```

Please check the link and do help, if you have any idea what's wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your app for you?

Comment: How do you set `@gallery` instance variable?

Comment: BTW this problem seems to be simple - my advice for you is to learn some basics about Ruby and Rails before trying to create own applications.

Comment: Not really, I was confused over a point where one page is being rendered inside the layouts/aplication page where it is not supposed to do that. Moreover I already tried with the heroku run rake db:migrate but it seems that's not the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the Gallery class have an instance method called `webmNew`?  If so, what is the @gallery variable set to?

Comment: Well I am passing  @gallery = Gallery.where(id: params[:id]) to the video1 controller, which takes the id of the uploaded video and then display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with below line.

```
@gallery = Gallery.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

you are getting back an object of ActiveRecord::Relation, not your model instance, thus the error since there is undefined method called webnew in ActiveRecord::Relation.

Doing @gallery = Gallery.where(id: params[:id]).first works because it is returning the first instance of the model that was found by the where.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dnyanarth for helping.